# Legality of discussions

Tags: discussion

How is it acceptable to discuss methods of taking over others' devices? Came here looking for help with security and I see inquiries almost all pertaining to taking control over products, aka stealing/theft.

Comment: I've moved this to our Meta site as it is more about what is ok/not ok to ask/answer than about a specific problem. Can you maybe add a link or two to questions which you consider problematic so we have the same things in mind when discussing this?

Comment: Examples! Examples, please!

Comment: What exactly are you talking about?  I don't see anything like that here.

Comment: If you provide some, any, example of stealing or theft, please post them here for us to review.  I'm here fairly regularly and I don't recall seeing anything similar to what you've described.

Answer (score 4):

You can discuss a lot of things that are illegal without falling afoul of the law. Imagine if you couldn't discuss murder? It'd be really hard to study case law or report the news.

There's also varying laws around the world when it comes to actions. So some action that might be illegal in one country could be perfectly legal in another.

Knowledge isn't illegal to possess or to share.

Comment: Perhaps instead of law I should've used moral compass and empathy, but keep doin u

Comment: Because discussing murder is equivalent to instructing others on how to compromise other people's possessions.

Comment: ermmm...1) no it isn't & 2) without examples all we can keep saying is 1) no it isn't.

Comment: Discussing how someone was murdered certainly is @ShuddaBeenCodin and that isn't illegal. Knowledge, possessed or given, is not illegal.